# Excluding phrases from text

Tags: python, list

Assuming I have such a sentence:

```
text = 'Romeo and Juliet is a tragedy written by William Shakespeare early in his career about two young star-crossed lovers whose deaths ultimately reconcile their feuding families'
```

and a list with phrases:

```
phrases = ['Romeo and Juliet', 'William Shakespeare', 'career', 'lovers', 'deaths', 'feuding families']
```

Is it possible to exclude these phrases from the text to get:

```
result = ['is', 'a', 'tragedy', 'written', 'by', 'early', 'in', 'his', 'about', 'two', 'young', 'star-crossed', 'whose', 'ultimately', 'reconcile', 'their']
```

I have used filter before but only with single words not phrases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace all your phrases with an empty string with [str replace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) and then use [str split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split the resulting string along the withspaces.

For example:

```
for phrase in phrases:
    text = text.replace(phrase, '')

result = text.split()

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate over the phrases and use the `replace`function from python to remove them from the string. After that you split the string at the spaces and should have your desired output.

Welcome to Stackoverflow btw (;

```
for phrase in phrases:
    text = text.replace(phrase, '')

result = text.split(' ')
result.remove('')
print(result)
```